# Progress Dialog not showing during a asynctask call

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

Ok so I am trying to get a progress dialog to show when data is being downloaded from the internet and being applied to the UI. My asynctask is working fine and it runs though all the steps, but it never shows the dialog ever. I don't know what I have done wrong here and I pretty much hit the wall. I even tried to put the async task into the new runnable thread and run it like that, that also did not show the dialog. I am calling the async task like this

```
    new runningMan().execute();
```

Here is the code that I am trying to run.

```
private class runningMan extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer>
{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        Log.d("Runningman: ", "Started running");
        //this method will be running on UI thread
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(PromotionMain.this, "Loading", "PleaseWait", true);

    }
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //parse the JSON string
        JSONParser jp = new JSONParser();
        try {
            Log.d(username , password);
            jp.parsesData(promos, myJson, pictureArray, pathArray, labelArray);
            Log.d("Runningman: ", "Finished parsing");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return 1;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        ArrayList<ListItem> listData = getListData();
        fillListView(listData);
        Log.d("Runningman: ", "Finished runing");
        //this method will be running on UI thread
        progress.dismiss();
    }

}
```

Thank you for any help with this.

Comment: Yes I see Started running Finished parsing and Finished running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call "super.onPreExecute();" and "super.onPostExecute(result);" after your code for progress dialog. Or better, get rid of them (if you don't have reasons for calling them).

Use the following code:

```
private class runningMan extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer>
{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        Log.d("Runningman: ", "Started running");
        //this method will be running on UI thread
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(PromotionMain.this, "Loading", "PleaseWait", true);
        super.onPreExecute();

    }
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //parse the JSON string
        JSONParser jp = new JSONParser();
        try {
            Log.d(username , password);
            jp.parsesData(promos, myJson, pictureArray, pathArray, labelArray);
            Log.d("Runningman: ", "Finished parsing");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return 1;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        ArrayList<ListItem> listData = getListData();
        fillListView(listData);
        Log.d("Runningman: ", "Finished runing");
        //this method will be running on UI thread
        progress.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

Comment: I change it, but it still is not showing. It may show for a blink but is not displaying like I think it should. It should display until the ui has been built right?

Comment: After this change, the progress dialog will surely work. If the dialog appears for a very short time, this means your doInBackground() method and other tasks before "progress.dismiss();" are finished very fast. For longer tasks, the progress dialog will be visible for more time.

Comment: Thank you I think I understand I will try to use this on something that takes a little longer to run.